# Need quiz scoring function

Tags: python

I have to create a basic 3 question quiz on farming. It needs to ask the 3 questions, output whether you got it correct or incorrect and if you got it incorrect you can try again. It also needs to have a score function.  I have completed the questions and the incorrect/correct part of the specification but no matter what I try I cannot get the score function to work. I have tried:

```
score = 0

def counter(score)
    score = score + 1

def counter(score)
    score = 0
    score = score + 1

def counter(score)
    global score
    score = 0
    score = score + 1
```

and then following that once the answer was correct the line read :

```
counter(score)
```

I have also tried

```
score = 0
```

then

```
score = score + 1
```

but nothing is working and I cannot figure out what is going wrong. It also needs to print how many the user got right at the end.

CODE:

```
score = 0

def quiz():
    print("Here is a quiz to test your knowledge of farming...")
    print()
    print()
    print("Question 1")
    print("What percentage of the land is used for farming?")
    print()
    print("a. 25%")
    print("b. 50%")
    print("c. 75%")
    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer == "c":
       print("Correct!")
       score = score + 1
   else:
       print("Incorrect.")
       answer = input("Try again! ")
         if answer == "c":
            print("Correct")
            score = score + 1
         else:
             print("Incorrect! Sorry the answer was C.")
    print()
    print()
    print("Question 2")
    print("Roughly how much did farming contribute to the UK economy in 2014.")
    print()
    print("a. £8 Billion.")
    print("b. £10 Billion.")
    print("c. £12 Billion.")
    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer == "b":
       print("Correct!")
       score = score + 1
   else:
       print("Incorrect.")
       answer = input("Try again! ")
         if answer == "b":
            print("Ccrrect!")
            score = score + 1
         else:
            print("Incorrect! Sorry the answer was B.")
   print()
   print()
   print("Question 3.")
   print("This device, which was invented in 1882 has revolutionised farming. What is it called?")
   print()
   print("a. Tractor")
   print("b. Wagon.")
   print("c. Combine.")
   answer == input("Make your choice. ")
     if answer == "a":
         print("Correct!")
         score = score + 1
    else:
         print("Incorrect.")
         answer == input("Try again! ")
            if answer == "a":
               print("Correct!")
               score = score + 1
          else:
              print("Incorrect! Sorry the answer was A.")

print("You got {0}/3 right!".format(score))
```

Comment: everything under a `def` needs to be indented.

Comment: Hint: [Functions can return something](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html).

Comment: If you're posting Python code, make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: it is all indented on my computer but when i copy and pasted it onto the site it went on with out indentation, ill fix it now.

Comment: You need to define what the scoring function does and it's interface (what arguments will be passed to it and what value(s) will it return). Once you've done this, the next step is coding it, followed by testing and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

A n00b (and working) way would be to do something like

```
score = 0

def quiz():
    global score
```

The `global` keyword makes use of the global variable (which you declared *outside* your function `quiz`). Since you've not indented your code properly it's unclear if you're printing the last statement inside or outside the `quiz` function, but that doesn't matter. If you place both `score` and printing inside the quiz function or both outside you'll be fine. Good luck with homework!

Answer (score 0):

So python scope is defined by indents (as mentioned by the comment above). So any statement that creates a layer of scope is seperated by an indent. Examples include classes, functions, loops, and boolean statements. Here is an example of this.

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.message = msg
    def print_msg(self):  # prints your message
        print self.message
    def is_hi(self):
        if self.message == "hi":
            return true
        else:
            return false
```

This shows the different layers of scope that can exist.
Your code is not working right now because you are defining a function and then putting nothing in its scope. You would have to put anything within the scope of the function for that error to go away but that is probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Operators** in any programming language are your bread and butter for transforming data from one state to another or for comparing data. We have three types: Arithmetic operators, Relational operators and Logical operators. It is crucial you understand them well and I would advise you to visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-operators-python/ for reference. I can see from your answer above that there is some confusion between the **assignment operator** and the **comparison operator**:

**This is the comparison operator:**

`answer == input("Make your choice. ")`

What you expect to happen is that an input is read from the keyboard and set into the answer variable, but what's actually happening is your testing for a conditional comparison, in this case between an empty variable (called answer) and a python **built-in function**. What will happen is python will silently return a boolean describing the outcome of the conditional statement but will never set your variable to the new value because you didn't use the assignment operator.

**This is the assignment operator:**

`answer = input("Make your choice. ")`

A single equal symbol can make a big difference!

Now your code will correctly set the value a user types from their keyboard into the answer variable thanks to the power of the assignment operator.

I've refactored your code below to demonstrate the difference between assignment and comparison operations. I've also demonstrated using the newline character (**\n**) to create spaces between your text blocks.

```py
import sys

def quiz():
    score = 0
    print("Here is a quiz to test your knowledge of farming...\n\n")

    print("Question 1")
    print("What percentage of the land is used for farming?")
    print("a. 25%")
    print("b. 50%")
    print("c. 75%")

    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer == "c":
        print("Correct!\n\n")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Sorry the answer was C.\n\n")

    print("Question 2")
    print("Roughly how much did farming contribute to the UK economy in 2014.\n")
    print("a. £8 Billion.")
    print("b. £10 Billion.")
    print("c. £12 Billion.")

    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer == "b":
        print("Correct!\n\n")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Sorry the answer was B.\n\n")

    print("Question 3.")
    print("This device, which was invented in 1882 has revolutionised farming. What is it called?\n")
    print("a. Tractor")
    print("b. Wagon.")
    print("c. Combine.")

    answer = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer == "a":
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Sorry the answer was A.")

    print("You got {}/3 right!".format(score))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    quiz()
```